# auto return type not deducing reference

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, return-type-deduction

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct C {
    int a;
    int& get() { return a; }
};
struct D {
    int a;
    int get() { return a; }
};
template <typename T>
auto foo(T o) { // no sample code is complete without a foo
    return o.get();
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    D d;
    c.a = 2;
    d.a = 42; // no sample code is complete without a 42
    std::cout << "c=" << c.a << ", d=" << d.a << "\n";
    c.get() = 3;
    //d.get() = 43;
    std::cout << "c=" << c.a << ", d=" << d.a << "\n";
    foo(c) = 4;  // <--- why won't this work?
    //foo(d) = 44;
    std::cout << "c=" << c.a << ", d=" << d.a << "\n";
}
```

Why won't the line marked compile? It seems that the copiler is deducing the return type of `foo<C>` to be `int` instead of the `int&` I would expect. Why is this and how can I get it to deduce the reference, too?

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ab909680836fd24

Comment: i hope someone will explain in proper terms, for the meanwhile consider that `T` in `foo` is deduced to be `C` not `C&`, hence it would be really bad if `auto` would deduce a `int&`, as then `foo` would be returning a refernece to a local variable

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks, that together with the `decltype(auto)` from the answers worked as I expected, but I still don't understand why

Comment: Note that `auto foo(T o)` passes in the `c` by copy.  Maybe want that to be `auto& foo(T& o)` to pass by reference, and `auto&` to return reference that has been picked out by the `o.get()`.  Or instead of `auto&` use `decltype(auto)`.  (Hmm, I thought putting parens around the return expression would make it an rvalue, but it didn't.  Maybe C++17 fixed that.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given `auto`, which is declared as a non-reference, so we're dealing with pass-by-value case. And [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) follows the rules of [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction); the reference part of `int&` will be ignored, then the deduced type is `int`.

You can use [`decltype(auto)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (since C++14) instead.

> type is `decltype(e)`, where `e` is the initializer.

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) foo(T&& o) { // no sample code is complete without a foo
    return o.get();
}
```

The return type is deduced as `decltype(o.get())`, and according to the rule of [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype),

> if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields `T&`;

`c.get()` returns `int&`, which is an lvalue, then we get the return type `int&` insteand of `int`.

BTW: Note that if `o` is still passed by-value, the returned reference would be dangled.

Comment: This works. I will have to go brush up on `auto` vs `decltype(auto)`

Comment: @Baruch Some explanations added. Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice answer. The parameter could be an lvalue reference like `decltype(auto) foo(T &o)`. Using a universal reference is not wrong but could be distracting. Since, it is good practice to always use a universal reference parameter along with a call to std::forward inside the function. Thus people refer to universal references as forwarding references to emphasis this principle.