# The right way for get template to return value: decltype(auto), auto&&, or

Tags: c++, templates, auto

The simple case is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429977/auto-return-type-not-deducing-reference)

However, I cant find a way to get a proper return result in given situations.
Lets consider basic 'get' function.

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) get_object(T&& a) {
   return a.object;
}
```

And my wish would be to:

```
struct Foo {
   int object;
};
// case 1: to return int (now returns int)
get_object(Foo());

// case 2: to return int& (now returns.. also int)
Foo a;
get_object(a);
```

For perfect forwarding function call decltype(auto) works as expected.
But I use this kind of 'get' functions pretty often in templates.
Is there some way to connect the input object qualifiers to return type?

I checked how is std::get for tuples made.
They have versions for each const&, & and &&.
Is this how it must be :( ?

So summary:
I want that get_object(T&) returned by &, get_object(T&&) return by value (or &&).

---

**Edit:**
As @NathanOliver pointed: std::forward(a).object is required in both cases - with decltype(auto) and auto&&. The first one requires also quotes.

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) get_object(T&& a) {
   return (std::forward<T>(a).object);
}
// or:
template<typename T>
auto&& get_object(T&& a) {
   return std::forward<T>(a).object;
}
// both gives case 1: int&&
get_object(Foo());

// both gives case 2: int&
Foo a;
get_object(a);
```

Just using auto&& (without forward) produces for case 1 wrong int&.
Probably those solutions are different in other cases, but that's out of scope for my case. But if anyone knows what's different - feel encouraged to share :D

But real question is: is returning int&& safe? Instead of lvalue (int). Is this int life extended what makes it safe?

Comment: Try `return std::forward<T>(a).object;`?

Comment: Why should it be `int` instead of `int&&`? (That's what the comment above together with `auto&&` would give.)

Comment: Also, there are other special cases you need to consider. For example what do you want to happen if the member is a lvalue reference or rvalue reference? There are different possibilities and if you want to reproduce `std::tuple`'s behavior, the built-in member access with forwarding behaves different from tuple elements in that case. That's why it has multiple overloads.

Comment: @user17732522 int&& with std::forward<T>(a).object seems to give proper answers for my simple cases. About the second comment.. Do not try to ruin my world.. :D
For my needs lvalue case is sufficient, but it seems that with references it also works returning references, which probably might not be the right way in all cases, but to much thinking for me :p

Comment: @user2561762 Maybe to be specific: `std::get` for tuples is a rvalue expression if the element type is rvalue reference and the tuple argument is a rvalue expression. However, member access will always produce an lvalue if the member has reference type (whether lvalue or rvalue).

Answer (score 1):

That's because `decltype(a.object)` is `int` because it's a member access expression, so it's giving the type of the member as opposed to the type of the expression that access it.

You need extra brackets to make it the `decltype` of an expression instead of a name:

```cpp
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) get_object(T&& a) {
   return (a.object);
   // You probably also want to forward the value category:
   // return (std::forward<T>(a).object);  // get_object(Foo{}) is now int&&
}
```

Comment: Or you could set the return type to `auto &&` and return without `(...)`.